# Run time variable is not resolved inside style element

Tags: aem

I am trying to provide the background image to a div by creating a variable in sightly.

```
<sly data-sly-test.file="${properties.image}" />
<div style="background: url(${file @ context='styleToken'});"></div>
```

it does not work.

```
 <div style="background: url();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `<div style="background-image:url('${properties.file@ context='styleString'}');" >`